# Vue Custom Directives: how to share a variable between hooks?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I want to share a variable among custom directive's hooks.

Example:

```
Vue.directive('demo',{
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    const index = setInterval(/* ... */) //I have an "index" here
  },
  unbind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    clearInterval(index) // I want to use "index" here
  }
})
```

How can I pass my value from `bind` to `unbind`?

P.S. The only workaround in my mind is to modify `el` in a way to attach an html-attribute "my-custom-index" in `bind` and to read it in `unbind`. But it's soooo hacky...

Comment: I agree it's hacky but it is also the recommended approach. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments. Quote: *'If you need to share information across hooks, it is recommended to do so through element’s dataset.'*

Comment: @skirtle Hm, I missed that in the docs. I guess your comment should be an answer ))

Comment: Not really a workaround, since directives don't have own instances and don't necessarily correspond to comp instances, sharing data on el is reasonable. Notice that dataset is string, may be better to store it as `el` property to keep it a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a [way to go](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments) to use html-attributes:

```
Vue.directive('demo',{
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) { 
    //save
    el.setAttribute('x-my-attr', index);
  },
  unbind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    //read
    const index = el.getAttribute('x-my-attr'); // The value is a string!
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The first option is to use `el.dataset` to store data. This is limited, however, since dataset can only keep strings.
What I did was use the `el` reference as an id to know what data corresponds to what, like so:

```
const data = []

Vue.directive('example',{
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    const index = setInterval(/* ... */) //I have an "index" here
    data.push({el, index})
  },
  unbind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    const dataIndex = data.findIndex(item => item.el === el)
    const { index } = data[dataIndex]
    clearInterval(index) // I want to use "index" here
    data.splice(dataIndex, 1)
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

That where the directive definition is must be in a JS module. So why not define your variables in the module. Then read and write it anywhere in the module scope.

like:

```
let va = 9
Vue.directive('demo',{
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    va = va + 1
    const index = setInterval(/* ... */) //I have an "index" here
  },
  unbind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    console.log(va)
    clearInterval(index) // I want to use "index" here
  }
})
```

Or you can use `this.va = 'covid-19'` and `var va = this.va`.

Or `el.dataset`.

Comment: What happens if you use the directive more than once on the same page?

Comment: Yup using a global is a wrong way to go, you want a per directive context